# How to show action bar when replace a fragment after hiding it on previous fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-lifecycle

I have an actionbar on MainActivity level (`mainActionBar`) and an actionbar on fragment level (`fragActionBar`). I have 3 fragments (A,B,C). I want `mainActionBar` to be shown when I'm accessing fragment A and B. On the other hand, I want `fragActionBar` to be shown when I'm accessing fragment C.

I use `replace()` when changing between fragments and use `addToBackStack` to save previous fragment so I can use `popBackStack` to back to previous fragment. The flow is like this : A<->B <->C. `fragActionBar` contains up button and if I press the up button it will back to fragment B. `mainActionBar` doesn't have up button, I use button outside toolbar/actionbar to change fragments between A<->B->C. So only C->B that is using up button.

I have succeeded to show `mainActionBar` when I'm on fragment A and B. I also have succeeded to show `fragActionBar` when I'm on fragment C. But when I go back to fragment B, the `mainActionBar` didn't show up. I try to put `supportActionBar?.show()` inside `onResume()`, but it didn't works. I also try to put `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()` inside `setNavigationOnClickListener`, still didn't works.

How can I show the `mainActionBar` when I get back to fragment B after visiting fragment C?

Comment: In Fragment C you replaced supportActionBar. And when you get back to B, you should set mainActionBar again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I need to use the toolbar I declared in MainActivity by passing the binding from MainActivity to other fragment. It is because I use a different toolbar in other fragment, that's why it won't affect the changes even  after I use `.show()`.